# Diffrence between Raw strings and Normal strings in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

For example:

Raw string

```
let str1 = #"The "swift 5" has abiliy to create raw strings."#
```

Normal string

```
let str2 = "The \"swift 5\" has abiliy to create raw strings."
```

Is that diffrence in only syntax?

Is the raw string introduced for only get ride of adding lot of backslashes in case of double quotes

Comment: Please read [SE-200](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)

Answer (score 4):

Raw strings were introduced by [SE-0200](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md). From [Paul Hudson's article on "How to use raw strings in Swift 5"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/162/how-to-use-raw-strings-in-swift) (emphasis mine):

> Swift 5  gives us the ability to specify a custom string delimiter
>   using the **hash symbol, `#`**, sometimes called a **hashtag or a pound sign**.
>   When you use `#` with a string it affects the way Swift understands
>   special characters in the string: **`\` no longer acts as an escape
>   character**, so `\n` literally means a backslash then an “n” rather than a
>   line break, and `\(variable)` will be included as those characters
>   rather than using string interpolation.
>
> So, these two strings are identical:
>
> ```
> let normalString = "\\Hello \\World"
> let rawString = #"\Hello \World"#
> ```

For more info: [Custom String Escaping](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-strings-from-raw-text-in-swift-5/)

Answer (score 1):

From [Cosmin Pupăză's article on "What’s New in Swift 5?"](https://www.raywenderlich.com/55728-what-s-new-in-swift-5):

> Swift 4.2 uses escape sequences to represent backslashes and quote
>   marks in strings:
>
> ```
> let escape = "You use escape sequences for \"quotes\"\\\"backslashes\" in Swift 4.2."
> let multiline = """
>                 You use escape sequences for \"\"\"quotes\"\"\"\\\"\"\"backslashes\"\"\"
>                 on multiple lines
>                 in Swift 4.2.
>                 """
> ```
>
> Swift 5 adds raw strings. You add `#` at the beginning and end of the
>   string so you can use backslashes and quote marks without issue. [[SE-0200](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)]:
>
> ```
> let raw = #"You can create "raw"\"plain" strings in Swift 5."#
> let multiline = #"""
>                 You can create """raw"""\"""plain""" strings
>                 on multiple lines
>                 in Swift 5.
>                 """#
> ```

[More Detail](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md)